# Convert JSON date in PHP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm new in Javascript, In PHP file I have script like so,

```
$JsonFormat = sprintf(
    '\/Date(%s%s)\/',
    $dateTime->format('U') * 1000,
    $dateTime->format('O')
);  

$dateTime->format('U') = Seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)   
$dateTime->format('O') = Difference to Greenwich time (GMT) in hours
```

which returns a data like this, and works fine.

> /Date(1542798236000+0800)/

I tried to redo the code using javascript like so,

```
  var dt = new Date();
  var newDate = new Date(Date.UTC(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate()));
  var newDate = '\/Date(' + newDate.getTime() + '+0800)\/';
```

But it returns like this

> /Date(1542758400000+0800)/

In the API I want to access, it says **"Login out of date"** which means the datetime probably not correct.

Timezone: "Asia/Manila"

How do I manage to get the correct datetime.

Comment: try >>>
new Date().toLocaleString();

Comment: You don't tell us how you defined $dateTime in your php script. Would be helpful to find the javascript equivalent!

Comment: This really sounds like a timezone issue. Are you sure both times are based on the same timezone?

Comment: Please check my updates above.

Comment: I checked my time now, its 8:00 PM but in the code returns "2018-11-21T11:58:27.556Z" so i think its 8 hours late